# How to pop up or search the knowledge base based on the chat content in the live chat window?

Tags: knowledge, liveagent, articles

I have set up live agent and knowledge base.

I can manually search the knowledge articles entering the keywords.

But i want to know is it possible as to search the knowledge articles based on the chat entered by user during live chat session ?
That is dynamically it should take the keywords entered by the customer in the live chat session and search the knowledge articles.

Is it possible in salesforce ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. Bear in mind, the conversation could be long and it would be very expensive from the API usage point of view to query the KB every time the customer sends a message.

What we do is, we have a pre-chat form, where our customers enter a subject and the case reason, when they submit the form and the agent accepts the case, the case is automatically created and opens in the agent screen, this causes the knowledge sidebar to automatically search articles based on the subject entered by the user.